# Node-mssql not able to connect to the server but with tedious it connects

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious, node-mssql

currently i'am using **tedious** package to connect to the database and do operations but i would like to switch to **node-mssql** (seems less messy).
The problem i'm getting is connection timeout:

```
originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to yyy:1433 in 15000ms
    code: 'ETIMEOUT',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
```

My config with tedious :

```
const config = {
  server: process.env.HOST, // update me
  authentication: {
    type: 'default',
    options: {
      userName: process.env.USER, // update me
      password: process.env.PASS, // update me
    },
  },
  options: {
    // If you are on Microsoft Azure, you need encryption:
    database: process.env.DB,
    rowCollectionOnDone: true, // update me
  },
};
```

My config with mssql :

```
const configMssql = {
  user: process.env.USER,
  password: process.env.PASS,
  server: process.env.HOST, // update me
  database: process.env.DB,
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: false, // for azure
    trustServerCertificate: false, // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
  },
};
```

or

```
const configMssqlString = `Server=${process.env.HOST},1433;Database=${process.env.DB};User Id=${process.env.USER};Password=${process.env.PASS};Encrypt=false`;
```

Can't figure out whats wrong

Comment: did you resolve it?
I opened an issue: https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/1438

Comment: @Doc999tor I was able do everything with mssql and not node-mssql